# Neo4j create graph that some nodes have more than one relationships

Tags: neo4j

Over my Neo4j I want to create this graph:

[image]

SO I tried to create some nodes and relationships with:

```
MERGE (D:POINT {NAME:'d'})<-[:LINKS]-(A:POINT {NAME:'a'})-[:LINKS]->(B:POINT {NAME:'b'})-[:LINKS]->(C:POINT {NAME:'c'})
```

But I cannot find out how I will create the relationships between `D` and `B` points also I cannot find out how I will link the `A` and `C` as well.

Do you have any Idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid unintentionally creating duplicate nodes and/or relationships, you must invoke `MERGE` on *individual* nodes and relationships.

To quote the [dev manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/#query-merge-introduction):

> When using MERGE on full patterns, the behavior is that either the
>   whole pattern matches, or the whole pattern is created. MERGE will not
>   partially use existing patterns — it’s all or nothing. If partial
>   matches are needed, this can be accomplished by splitting a pattern up
>   into multiple MERGE clauses.

For example, to properly create your graph without any duplicate nodes or relationships:

```
MERGE (A:POINT {NAME:'a'})
MERGE (B:POINT {NAME:'b'})
MERGE (C:POINT {NAME:'c'})
MERGE (D:POINT {NAME:'d'})
MERGE (A)-[:LINKS]->(B)
MERGE (A)-[:LINKS]->(C)
MERGE (A)-[:LINKS]->(D)
MERGE (B)-[:LINKS]->(C)
MERGE (D)-[:LINKS]->(B)
```

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE` seems to be the natural way to me for creating nodes and relationships.

```
CREATE (D:POINT {NAME:'d'})<-[:LINKS]-(A:POINT {NAME:'a'})
   , (A)-[:LINKS]->(B:POINT {NAME:'b'})<-[:LINKS]-(D)
   , (B)-[:LINKS]->(C:POINT {NAME:'c'})<-[:LINKS]-(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by doing a `MATCH` before a `MERGE` eg. FOR the relationship between `A` and `D` do:

```
MATCH (A:POINT {NAME:'a'}),(B:POINT {NAME:'d'}) MERGE (A)-[:LINKS]->(B)
```