# Avoid duplicate entires when Inserting Excel or CSV-like entries into a neo4j graph

Tags: excel, csv, neo4j

I have the following .xslx file:

[image: Xlsx entries]

My software regardless tis language will return the following graph:

[image: Generated Graph]

My software iterates line by line and on each line iteration executes the following query

```
MERGE (A:POINT {x:{xa},y:{ya}}) MERGE (B:POINT {x:{xb},y:{yb}}) MERGE (C:POINT {x:{xc},y:{yc}}) MERGE (A)-[:LINKS]->(B)-[:LINKS]->(C) MERGE (C)-[:LINKS]->(A)
```

Will this avoid by inserting duplicate entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312314/neo4j-create-graph-that-some-nodes-have-more-than-one-relationships/48312452#48312452) question, yes it will avoid writing duplicate entries.

The query above will match any existing nodes and it will avoid to write duplicates.

A good rule of thumb is on each node that it may be a duplicate write it into a seperate MERGE query and afterwards write the merge statements for each relationship between 2 nodes.

## Update

After some experiece when using asyncronous technologies such [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) or even parallel threads you must verify that you read the next line **AFTER** you inserted the previous one. The reason why is because is that doing multiple insertions asyncronously may result having multiple nodes into your graph that are actually the same ones.

In node.js project of mine I read the excell file like:

```javascript
const iterateWorksheet=function(worksheet,maxRows,row,callback){

process.nextTick(function(){
  //Skipping first row
  if(row==1){
    return iterateWorksheet(worksheet,maxRows,2,callback);
  }

  if(row > maxRows){
    return;
  }

  const alphas=_.range('A'.charCodeAt(0),config.excell.maxColumn.charCodeAt(0));

  let rowData={};

  _.each(alphas,(column) => {
    column=String.fromCharCode(column);
    const item=column+row;
    const key=config.excell.columnMap[column];
    if(worksheet[item] && key ){
      rowData[key]=worksheet[item].v;
    }
  });

  // The callback is the isertion over a neo4j db
  return callback(rowData,(error)=>{
    if(!error){
      return iterateWorksheet(worksheet,maxRows,row+1,callback);
    }
  });
});


 }
```

As you see I visit the next line when I successfully inserted the previous one. I find no way yet to serialize the inserts like most conventional RDBMS's does.

In case or web or server applications another *UNTESTED* approach is to use queue servers such as RabbitMQ or similar in order to queue the queries. Then the code responsimble for insertion will read from the queue so the whole isolation should be in the queue.

Furthermore ensure that all inserts are into a transaction.

Comment: Keep in mind that MERGE takes locks in your graph, so even run in parallel you shouldn't see duplicate nodes or relationships (depending on your Neo4j version...there were some versions in 3.1.x that had a bug around this). Also you are correct that doing a MERGE for each relationship is better than doing a merge of a multi-relationship path. In fact it would be better if the rows in your files only identified 2 nodes and a relationship, not 3 nodes and two relationships.

Comment: Also on 3.3.1 community that I am running has this bug of duplicate entries when I do parallel merges on same nodes.

Comment: Have you added any constraints in your graph? Adding a node key constraint on :POINT(x,y) ought to take care of the merging of duplicate nodes.